# How to prevent superscript getting too close to line above

Tags: math-mode, arrays

The below code is working but the superscript H appears to be too close to the line above.

How can I put some space in between the H and the line right above it? Thx.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$
\left( \begin{array}{c|c}
        { I } & { 0 } \\ \hline
        { 0 } &
        { I - \frac{1}{\tau_1}
        \left( \begin{array}{c} 
        { 1 } \\ \hline
        { u_{2} }
  \end{array} \right)
        \left( \begin{array}{c}
        { 1 } \\ \hline
        { u_{2} }
  \end{array} \right)^H 
        }
  \end{array} \right)
$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\dfrac` instead of nesting arrays in array?

Comment: @Bernard that would be better markup probably but the superscript H would still be close the the hline in the outer array (I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know this wouldn't solve the problem, but I wondered whether there was a specific reason.

Comment: @Bernard Thx for the suggestion. I had not used  `\dfrac` before but upon trial my impression is that the use of an array and `\hline` would convey what is meant by this formula better given the longer separating line and also help me maintain better code consistency across vectors or matrices with different number of elements.

Comment: I've posted a solution with a short code with a longer line in fraction (easily turned into a macro) and a=vertical spacing for the exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to add a blank line and back up a bit (although this does over-print the vertical rule)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{array}{c|c}
        { I } & { 0 } \\ \hline
&\\[-5pt]
        { 0 } &
        { I - \frac{1}{\tau_1}
        \left( \begin{array}{c} 
        { 1 } \\ \hline
        { u_{2} }
  \end{array} \right)
        \left( \begin{array}{c}
        { 1 } \\ \hline
        { u_{2} }
  \end{array} \right)^H 
        }
  \end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Her is a very simple way to have longer  lines with `\dfrac` and  prevent the superscript from touching the line above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
\left( \begin{array}{c|c}
        { I } & { 0 } \\ \hline
        { 0 } &
        { I - \frac{1}{\tau_1}
        \left( \dfrac{1}{\enspace u_{2}\enspace }\right)
        \left( \dfrac{1}{\enspace u_{2}\enspace } \right)^{\mkern-6mu H\strut}
        }
  \end{array} \right)
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just using `kbordermatrix` package associated with `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6}` as alternative with few steps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6}\begin{array}{l|cc}
I&0 &\\ \hline
0& I-\frac{1}{\tau_1}\Bigl(\frac 1{u_2}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac 1{u_2}\Bigr)^H&
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]